# Powershell move user\appdata(roaming) folders to user\appdata\roaming

Tags: powershell

I am moving my folder redirection store to a new server.

However the structure for appdata appears to now be users\AppData\Roaming\ as opposed to the old structure
users\AppData(Roaming)\

I am trying to move all the folders from the old structure to the new structure for a bunch of users folders.

I am assuming i need to use some sort of loop to check each folder.

Would something like this work?

```
$folderlist = ("foldertwo", "folderthree")
foreach ($folder in $folderlist)
{
if (!(Test-Path "P:\users$\%username%\AppData\Roaming"))
{
    mkdir ("P:\users$\%username%\AppData\Roaming") | Out-Null
}
Copy-Item P:\users$\%username%\AppData(Roaming)\* P:\users$\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ -recurse -Container
}
```

I am pretty new to powershell so scripting is not my best.

Comment: AFAIK %AppData% is an environment variable (in PowerShell `$env:APPDATA`) always poining to the `Roaming` subfolder in `AppData`. Inside this AppData folder there is also a subfolder `LocalLow` and a subfolder `Local`. The latter is found via environment variable `%LocalAppData%` or in PowerShell syntax `$env:LOCALAPPDATA`. There is no such folder by name of `AppData(Roaming)`.. As for your code, you are iterating over an array of foldernames, but never use variable `$folder`. Also, you cannot use the `%SomeVar%` [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) in PowerShell.

Comment: @Theo, would a UNC path be needed in this instance? Or is it okay to use the drive letter?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I would always use UNC paths when it comes to copying stuff from one server to another. Mapped driveletters can change and are personal, so if you run your script as another user, the mapped drive would probably not exist. In this case, I would advise the OP to investigate if what he/she is trying to do is not just a question of reading things wrong and have a closer look at the folder structure as it **really** is.

Comment: @Theo The path AppData(Roaming) is one folder. This should be split like this USER\APPDATA\ROAMING But for some reason the current GPO has messed it up hence building a whole new one. I need a script to createa new APPDATA folder and the ROAMING folder within it, then have the script move all the content over to this and remove the old APPDATA(ROAMING) Is this possible?

Comment: For neatness, yes, but if your GPO created that folder it should work for the users doesn't it? I wouldn't tinker with that simply by moving all documents to the now desired folder structure without first changing the policy, because otherwise you'll probably run into users getting access denied

Comment: @Theo policy is still in place. What i have done is copy the current store to a new share, set the permissions. Tested a logon with a test account but noticed it created the APPDATA/ROAMING instead of using the current one that is there. Now this is due to the new policy. So before i make the new policy completely live i need fix the folder structure for the APPDATA for all users folders.

Comment: Any comment on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Having read the comments, here a **partial** piece of code, as I think you best use RoboCopy to do the heavy lifting of copying all from the `AppData(Roaming)` folders to the new `AppData\Roaming` folder.

Please test on a dummy user first to figure out what switches to use on robocopy.
Then of course also test if the user permissions on the new path are correct (inherited from the `P:\Users$\<username>` folder)

```
$userShare = 'P:\Users$'      # if running on the server, otherwise best use the UNC path

# loop through tyhe folders inside the user share (1st level only)
Get-ChildItem -Path $userShare -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Processing user $($_.Name)"
    $destinationDir = Join-Path $_.FullName -ChildPath ('AppData\Roaming')
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationDir -PathType Container)) {
        Write-Host "Creating folder '$destinationDir'"
        $null = New-Item -Path $destinationDir -ItemType Directory
    }
    $wrongRoamingDir = Join-Path $_.FullName -ChildPath ('AppData(Roaming)')
    if (Test-Path -Path $wrongRoamingDir -PathType Container) {
        #############################################################################################
        # here is where you start copying everything from the $wrongRoamingDir to the $destinationDir.
        # I would suggest using RoboCopy for that using switches like
        # Robocopy /MIR $wrongRoamingDir  $destinationDir
        # or
        # Robocopy /S /E $wrongRoamingDir  $destinationDir
        #
        # Please test on a dummy user first. For more robocopy switches, have a look at
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy
        # https://www.windows-commandline.com/robocopy-command-syntax-examples/
        #############################################################################################
    }
}
```